# Xamarin/Android - Issue reading locally stored photo from camera - no read access

Tags: c#, java, android, mono, xamarin

I'm trying to create a simple test app to take photos in Android, using Xamarin. When I get this app working (or so I hope), i'll use the code in a real app that I'm working on. I'm using the following recipe from Xamarin as my basis:

http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/

The major difference is that I need to store images locally, and not on the SD card. I'm able to successfully take a picture (with the Android simulator). I can see the file in the file structure using ADB and can successfully copy and open the file on my PC. However, I'm unsuccessfull in accessing the file in the app, probably due to user rights.

Please note that I was successfull in creating my own .txt files, and reading them back using either System.IO and Java.IO.

Please review the following code. My app crashes when using "System.IO.File.ReadAllText" and gives me "Access to the path "/data/data/CameraAppDemo.CameraAppDemo/files/photo.jpg" is denied.". And whatever I try (absolute, relative paths, uri's), objBitmap is always null.

ADB says that "photo.jpg" has -rwxrwx--- rights, and though I'm not entirely sure, I think that should be more than sufficient

On the other hand, maybe the intent still has a lock on "photo.jpg"? Or something else is going on...

And one final note, I'm using System.IO.File.ReadAllText just for testing purposes. I experimented with stream readers as well, but with the same result. Also, though I believe this step is unnecessary, I enabled "WriteExternalStore" in the Manifest

```
namespace CameraAppDemo
{
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        using Android.App;
        using Android.Content;
        using Android.Content.PM;
        using Android.Graphics;
        using Android.OS;
        using Android.Provider;
        using Android.Widget;

        using Java.IO;

        using Environment = Android.OS.Environment;
        using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;

        [Activity(Label = "Camera App Demo", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
                private File _file;
                private string _basePath;
                private ImageView _imageView;

                protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
                {
                        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                        var objBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(_file.AbsolutePath) ;
                        Console.WriteLine ("objBitmap = null : " + (objBitmap == null).ToString ());

                        var strOutput = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (FileManager.BasePath + "/photo.jpg");
                        Console.WriteLine (strOutput);
                }

                protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
                {
                        base.OnCreate(bundle);
                        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                        FileManager.SetupFolderStructure();

                        if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures())
                        {
                                Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
                                _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

                                button.Click += TakeAPicture;
                        }
                }

                private bool IsThereAnAppToTakePictures()
                {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                        IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);

                        return availableActivities != null && availableActivities.Count > 0;
                }

                private void TakeAPicture(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
                {
                        System.IO.Directory.Delete (FileManager.BasePath, true);
                        _basePath = FileManager.BasePath;

                        _file = new Java.IO.File (_basePath, "photo.jpg");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));
                        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
        }
}

//Part of the FileManager class:

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace CameraAppDemo
{
        public class FileManager
        {
                public static string BasePath {
                        get { 
                                var libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 

                                if (Directory.Exists (libraryPath) == false) {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory (libraryPath);
                                }

                                return libraryPath;
                        }
                }
     }
}
```

==== Edit ====

It seems that I'm simply not able to read the file. As an ex-webdeveloper, I'm fairly new to programming for mobile, let alone the combo of C# and Java and I'm still learning a lot.

Anyway, I added the following lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("Setting file :" + _file.SetReadable (true));
Console.WriteLine("Can read :" + _file.CanRead());
```

Both cases return False. I can't read the file, and I am unable to give read access.

So, any ideas? Is this by design? Can I tell the Intent for taking images to give me read access, or is there another workaround?

If everything fails, I'm hoping to workaround the problem by saving to the SD card first and then copying the file to the local filesystem. But that's something I rather would not do; I can't guarantee that the end users have an SD card, and the pictures should not be deleted by accident.

Comment: Can you upload your solution zipped somewhere? I may have a look :)

Comment: Thank you kindly! 

Though I am not sure about the way things work, I now have the theory that the camera intent (thus the build-in camera app) becomes the owner of the photo and not the test app itself, which is the reason why the test app can't access the photo. I think that creating a content provider probably is the right thing to do (see http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.nl/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html), but I was unsuccessful in doing so either (second project in solution).

My code is here:
http://www.mobowski.com/temp/CameraAppDemo_2.zip

Comment: i used the same xamarin example to try to take a picture and then display it in the app.
My problem is that after aking the picture and approving it. The app never calls onActivityResult().